# Play mp4/youtube movie while recording with camera

Tags: ios, video-capture

I'm developing my first iOS app, and I need to record a video with the camera while playing a youtube video embedded in a UIWebView. The problem is, the video stops playing when I start the capture.

Is there any workaround? I thought of playing the video in an openGL texture, then play the audio at the same time, but I don't know how to do. I don't need the player to have control buttons, etc.
I've tried to use the [RosyWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/RosyWriter.zip) sample code and change the input source.

How can this be done?

[EDIT]
I finnaly solved my problem in another way. I don't use RosyWriter anymore, but AVCamRecorder, and for playing video, I get the url of the .mp4 file with [PSYoutubeExtractor](https://github.com/steipete/PSYouTubeExtractor), then i play it via MPMoviePlayer.
I had to set [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionSetCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil]

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't uderstand what you are trying to do. PSYoutubeExtractor doen't record anything, it's only designed to give you the direct MP4 url. To record a tune/movie, you should use an AVAsset, then export it to mp3/mp4.

I'm really sorry, but this project was for my internship in a company, and I havn't keep any piece of code anymore. But if you have a precise problem I already faced, I can try to help you.

Good luck.